# Javascript Regarding the Limit Of a Users Input

Tags: javascript

I must be missing something here,

my understanding is if the user types a number greater than 1000000000, the system will not allow it, what am i missing? It must be something small.

```
switch (validationType)
    {          
        case ValidationType.NONE :
        validationFunction = String.Empty;
        break;

        case ValidationType.NUMBERS:
        validationFunction = "validateNumber(event)";
        break;                               

        case ValidationType.ALPHANUMERIC:
        validationFunction = "validateAlphanumeric(event)";
        break;

        case ValidationType.ALPHABETS:
        validationFunction = "validateAlphabets(event)";
        break;                

        case ValidationType.WEBSITE :
        validateWebsite = "ValidateWebsite";
        break;

    }            

<input type="text" id="@textBoxID" style="width:105px"  maxlength="200" 
value="@answer" onkeyup="@validationFunction" />  

function validateNumber(event)
{
if (event.target.value > 1000000000)
{
    event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `event.target.value` is a *string*?

Comment: i put a breakpoint on preventDefault and it gets hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onkeypress` rather than `onkeyup`. The `keyup` event happens too late to prevent the default action.

```js
function validateNumber(event) {
  if (event.target.value > 1000000000) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="validateNumber(event)">
```